# Why are two numbers subtracted from each other causing a NAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, nan

I'm working on the following nodejs javascript code. I am subtracting two valid numbers from each other and receiving NAN as a result.

Any clues why this is?

```
stringLength = process.stdout.colums - "Spaces: aa".length;
console.log(process.stdout.columns); //returns 80
console.log("Spaces: aa".length); //returns 10
console.log(eval(process.stdout.colums - "Spaces: aa".length)); //returns NAN
console.log(stringLength); //returns NAN
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Typo on "colums": eval(process.stdout.colums - "Spaces: aa".length)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its the typo (`colums` v/s `columns`) that is causing the issue.

```
process.stdout.colums - "Spaces: aa".length; // undefined - 10 = NaN | Always, not even Evil (eval) can help
```

should be

```
process.stdout.columns - "Spaces: aa".length;
```

Comment: I feel like quite a idiot for not noticing that. I thought I was covering my bases with the eval(), but apparently I copied and pasted my previous line without it without realizing it.

Comment: @joshua-anderson Never mind, Don't use eval which i think you know anyways... :) See even Evil can't help...